# Why does the "contact" page link to Google, Facebook, and Yahoo?

Tags: discussion, contact

The [contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) on each Stack Exchange site links to Facebook, Yahoo, and Google:

[image: screenshot]

I am puzzled.  If I have an issue for which I need to contact Stack Exchange, why would I find links to Facebook, Yahoo, and Google helpful?

Comment: Many sign up/login through Google, FB or Yahoo. I think that is for them if they have problems having trouble in logging in.

Comment: @NogShine Ah... that is not obvious *at all*, but it's a very plausible explanation.

Comment: Fwiw those were always meant to be a temporary experiment. While we did see a good drop in the amount of third-party support requests when that was implemented, the volume has increased and we are working on alternate ways of handling the contact page to catch these requests without having out-of-place icons at the top. Those *will* eventually disappear.